# How to get/put these XAML data source values to/from C# code-behind in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, collections

I am learning the WPF.

Taking into account the XAML code for a WPF application:

```xml
<Window x:Class="_0SE_BridgingCodeBehind.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:col="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350"    Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">

   <Window.Resources>
       <col:ArrayList x:Key="MyDataSource">
           <sys:DateTime>1/2/2003 5:00:00</sys:DateTime>
           <sys:DateTime>4/5/2006 13:13:13</sys:DateTime>
           <sys:DateTime>7/8/2009 23:59:59</sys:DateTime>
       </col:ArrayList>
   </Window.Resources>
   <Canvas>
       <ListBox Width="200" Height="100"
             ItemsSource="{StaticResource MyDataSource}">
             <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                       <Label Content="{Binding DayOfWeek}" 
                          Width="80" Background="Red" />
                       <Label Content="{Binding DayOfYear}" 
                          Width="50" Background="Yellow" />
                       <Label Content="{Binding TimeOfDay}" 
                          Background="LightBlue" />
                   </StackPanel>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       </ListBox>
   </Canvas>
</Window>
```

[image]

from codepoject article "[WPF Lists/Views - A Visual Quick Start](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33650/WPF-Lists-Views-A-Visual-Quick-Start)" (section "Data Templates"),
how can I modify the project code in order:

- to add to the 3 existing static values of in `MyDataSource` the 4th one, for example, the value `4/4/2013 13:12:13` in C# code (`MainWindow.xaml.cs`)?
- to get in C# code the 2nd DateTime value `4/5/2006 13:13:13` in `MyDataSource` (currently inin XAML code)?

Update:
Having followed [Henk Holterman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16059170/2031316) (with minor changes):

```xml
<Canvas>
    <ListBox Width="200" Height="100"
      x:Name="myListBox"
      ItemsSource="{StaticResource MyDataSource}"
```

I've got rendered the values from C# (having lost them from XAML, though I do not want them) or XAML values in C#, but not both.

Comment: Do you really want to _mix_ xaml and C# data?

Comment: Nope, I just want to reuse what I've learned in that series of articles (it was 3d article) and have some sequencing in my learning (+ make some  exercises instead of just running ready code) instead of jumping to other unrelated texts without common. I've spent quite a time having read 3 big articles and there was no  bridge to C# at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea:

```
<ListBox Width="200" Height="100" 
      x:Name="myListbox"
      d:ItemsSource="{StaticResource MyDataSource}"   // design-time data
>
   ...
</ListBox>
```

And in MainForm_Loaded or the constructor:

```
 var data = new ObservableCollection<DateTime> { new DateTime(2013,4,17), ... };
 myListbox.ItemsSource = data;
```

Comment: I updated my question with full .XAML code. How is `d:` (in `d:ItemsSource=`) defined? I managed to render values from C# (though `x:Name="myListBox"`, note capital "B") but how can I get the values from XAML into C#?

Comment: _how can I get the values from XAML into C#?_ Possible but in practice you don't want to do that.

Comment: `d:` is design-only, it's in some of the templates (try New Page or New UserControl)